# Linking/Makefile trouble between 3 .c/.h files and a main

Tags: c, makefile, c99

I have 2 .h files that contain definitions for functions, and 2 .c files related to the .h files. There is a third .c file (not main) that has a header file and wants to use functions from the other 2 .c files. Using the makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c99 -I headers

main: main.o carFunctions.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) build/main.o build/carFunctions.o -o main
carFunctions.o: source/carFunctions.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  source/carFunctions.c -o build/carFunctions.o
linkedList.o: source/linkedList.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c source/linkedList.c -o build/linkedList.o
fileManage.o: source/fileManage.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c source/fileManage.c -o build/fileManage.o
main.o: source/main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c source/main.c -o build/main.o
clean:
        rm -i build/*.o
```

results in the error:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -I headers -c source/main.c -o build/main.o
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -I headers -c  source/carFunctions.c -o build/carFunctions.o
source/carFunctions.c: In function ‘test’:
source/carFunctions.c:9:9: warning: ‘tes3t’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   tes3t = push(tes3t,"TEST");
         ^
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -I headers build/main.o build/carFunctions.o -o main
build/carFunctions.o: In function `test':
carFunctions.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `push'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:5: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

The three .c files for functions are as follows:

carFunctions.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "carFunctions.h"
#include "linkedList.h"
#include "fileManage.h"

void test()
{
  LL* tes3t;
  tes3t = push(tes3t,"TEST");
  printf("it works?");
}
```

fileManage.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fileManage.h"

void test2()
{
  printf("fileman");
}
```

and linkedList.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linkedList.h"

struct LLStruct
{
  char* plateNum;
  struct LLStruct* next;
};

LL* push(LL* myList, char* data)
{
  LL* newNode = malloc(sizeof(LL));
  if(newNode != NULL)
  {
    newNode->plateNum = data;
    newNode->next = myList;
    return newNode;
  }
  else
  {
    return myList;
  }
}
```

The header files:
carFunctions.h:

```
#ifndef CARFUN
#define CARFUN

void test();

#endif
```

fileManage.h:

```
#ifndef FILEMAN
#define FILEMAN

void test2();

#endif
```

linkedList.h:

```
#ifndef LINKLIST
#define LINKLIST

typedef struct LLStruct LL; // Defines a structure for linked lists as "LL"
LL* push(LL* myList, char* data); // Adds an item to the linked list
#endif
```

And finally, main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "carFunctions.h"

int main()
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

I am not really too sure where the error is coming from, as I don't think there are any missing brackets. It may be the file linking/makefile, but I am not good enough with file linking to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two things going on here:

- First:

  ```
  source/carFunctions.c: In function ‘test’:
  source/carFunctions.c:9:9: warning: ‘tes3t’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     tes3t = push(tes3t,"TEST");
  ```

  This is showing you that you passed an uninitialized pointer as the first argument to the function `push`. Since the pointer is uninitialized, it could contain anything at all, pointing to any arbitrary place in memory, and the behavior of your program when you run it could vary wildly depending on what happens to be at that memory address.

  However, this is a warning, which means it's not ultimately responsible for the failure of your build process. (Often warnings can show the underlying reasons for more confusing errors that appear later on, so it's good to pay attention to them, though.)
- Second:

  ```
  build/carFunctions.o: In function `test':
  carFunctions.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `push'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  ```

  This is showing you that the linker wasn't able to find the compiled machine code for the function `push`. In this case, that's because you simply didn't include the object file which contains that machine code (`linkedList.o`) in the linker command line. Under different circumstances, this kind of error can sometimes mean that you made a mistake in the definition of a function and forgot to include the appropriate header file to allow the compiler to catch that mistake.

Comment: So I need to link carFunctions.o and the two other .o Files? How should I do that without creating another .o object?

Comment: Yes, you need to link all three of the object files, not only two as you did. You can do that in the way I mentioned in the question, by adding `linkedList.o` into the command line you use to run the linker, right along with the other two object files. I'm somewhat confused about why you think that would create another `.o` object file, so let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not great with the concept of linking, I was planning on linking linkedList.o and fileManage.o to carFunctions.c, and then carfunctions.o to main.o, but I don't think that would work because you cant link .c and .o files together.

Comment: Right... you can only link .o files together. (Well, you can also link them with .a files, but those are not much more than collections of .o files going under a different name.) I would definitely suggest reading some background material to get more familiar with what linking does.

Comment: For further clarification, I wanted carFunctions.c to use the functions in  fileManage.c and linkedList.c, without the functions in fileManage.c and linkedList.c being able to use the functions in carFunctions.c.


Thanks for the suggestion, I think ill have to read up on file linking(it was very poorly explained to me).

Comment: Ah, well that's not something you would usually enforce with the compiler or linker, though it's sort of possible - but that's going beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I might be overestimating what the linker does, going to have to look it up, as I thought it was completely possible to do that with the linker. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should fix the warning about the uninitialized variable `tes3t`.

Given you have (e.g.) /home/me/src:

Put all `.c` and `.h` files in /home/me/src/source

Create /home/me/src/build

Put `Makefile` in /home/me/src

Given that, here is a fixed Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c99 -I headers

OBJS += build/main.o
OBJS += build/carFunctions.o
OBJS += build/linkedList.o
OBJS += build/fileManage.o

build/main: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o main

build/carFunctions.o: source/carFunctions.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  source/carFunctions.c -o build/carFunctions.o

build/linkedList.o: source/linkedList.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c source/linkedList.c -o build/linkedList.o

build/fileManage.o: source/fileManage.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c source/fileManage.c -o build/fileManage.o

build/main.o: source/main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c source/main.c -o build/main.o

clean:
    rm -f build/*.o build/main
```

---

Better yet, here is a simpler version that uses wildcards:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c99 -I headers

OBJS += build/main.o
OBJS += build/carFunctions.o
OBJS += build/linkedList.o
OBJS += build/fileManage.o

build/main: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o main

build/%.o: source/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f build/*.o build/main
```